# jqueryui calendar does not render after upgrading project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

After upgrading my project from ASP.NET MVC2 to MVC3, simply calendar partial view no longer renders.  The code for this view is listed below.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AkwiMemorial.Models.CalendarModel>" %>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#DateStr').val(dateText);
        $('form').trigger('submit');   }});
    });
</script>


 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>   
 <div>
   <div id="datepicker"></div>
   <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DateStr)%>
</div>
 <% } %>
```

Any ideas?  TIA.

**Edit 1:**

To see if this is a problem with my original project, I modified Home/Index view on a new MVC3 project as shown below. When I execute, I get error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".  This is using jquery-1.5.1.min.js.

```
@model DateTime     

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
         });
</script>

 @using ( Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBox("datepicker", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" });    
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Why is this not working?

** Edit 2: **

Got jquery calendar to display in MVC3 using the following partial view:

```
@model DateTime

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="datepicker">
        @Html.TextBox("date", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })    
    </div>    
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $('#date').val(dateText);
                $('form').trigger('submit');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now back to the original problem.

Comment: If you look at the source after the page is rendered does the javascript look right?  Do your links to the scripts and styles all work correctly when viewing the source?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes,javescript same as original source minus the part enclosed in Html.BeginForm() which has been replaced by the form tag.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in firebug or the equivalent developer tools in a different browser?

Comment: Yes.  IE script debugger breaks with error "Object doesn't support this property or method" in jquery-1.6.1.min.js, line 16 character 15120, even with all of my script references in place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it fixed by upgrading to the latest version of jquery UI and jquery.

Comment: Thanks for response. I went ahead and downloaded jquery.ui version 1.8.13 core and datepicker, and changed page to use jquery 1.5.1 but cannot see calendar.

Comment: what versions of jquery and jquery UI did you upgrade to?  I just downloaded jquery 1.6.1.min andd jquery UI 1.8.13 but this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, my guess is that problem is with the nested `div`'s. The default css of the browser could be playing a part here. Trying setting `z-index` of the `datepicker` div to a higher value.

Comment: Thanks but that does not fix problem with a z-index of 10.  Please note that this code was working fine in MVC2.